# scp not running .bashrc or .bash_profile before copying file

Tags: ssh, bashrc, scp

My `.bash_profile` has the line `export path_shortcut=/some/file/path` (not wrapped in any conditionals), but calling `scp file.txt target_computer:$path_shortcut` still copies `file.txt` to the target computer's home directory instead of `/some/file/path`.

I've tried adding `echo .bash_profile run` at the end of .bash_profile and `echo .bashrc run` at the end of .bashrc, but neither message is printed out, though I'm not sure if either message would be printed out if `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` were run anyway.

Running `ssh` runs `.bash_profile`, and I can then call `cd $path_shortcut` without issue.

Any debugging advice or relevant tutorials would be welcome too; I'm quite new to `ssh` and `scp` :)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the remote `.bash_profile`, since `$path_shortcut` will be expanded by the local shell